# Photo capture on Windows Store App for Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

Well, my question is simple:
How do I capture pictures with a `Windows Store App` for `Windows Phone 8.1`, using the camera?
The samples on MSDN use `Windows.Media.Capture.CameraCaptureUI`, which is not usable on Windows Phone, or are for `Silverlight`.
I can't find any doc or sample specifically for Windows Phone app using Windows Runtime.
If someone knows, or even have the doc for this, I would be glad.

Comment: Do you want a Windows Store app or Windows Phone app?

Comment: Windows Store app. But for Windows Phone. (Windows phone app using the Windows Runtime).

Answer (score 48, accepted):

In WP8.1 Runtime (also in Silverlight) you can use [MediaCapture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.media.capture.mediacapture.aspx). In short:

```
// First you will need to initialize MediaCapture
Windows.Media.Capture.MediaCapture  takePhotoManager = new Windows.Media.Capture.MediaCapture();
await takePhotoManager.InitializeAsync();
```

If you need a preview you can use a [CaptureElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.captureelement):

```
// In XAML: 
<CaptureElement x:Name="PhotoPreview"/>
```

Then in the code behind you can start/stop previewing like this:

```
// start previewing
PhotoPreview.Source = takePhotoManager;
await takePhotoManager.StartPreviewAsync();
// to stop it
await takePhotoManager.StopPreviewAsync();
```

Finally to take a Photo you can for example take it directly to a file [CapturePhotoToStorageFileAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh700836.aspx) or to a Stream [CapturePhotoToStreamAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh700840.aspx):

```
ImageEncodingProperties imgFormat = ImageEncodingProperties.CreateJpeg();

// a file to save a photo
StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(
        "Photo.jpg", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

await takePhotoManager.CapturePhotoToStorageFileAsync(imgFormat, file);
```

If you want to capture video then [here is more information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh452791.aspx).

Also don't forget to add `Webcam` in `Capabilities` of your manifest file, and `Front/Rear Camera` in `Requirements`.

---

In case you need to choose a Camera (fornt/back), you will need to get the Camera Id and then initialize `MediaCapture` with desired settings:

```
private static async Task<DeviceInformation> GetCameraID(Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Panel desired)
{
    DeviceInformation deviceID = (await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(DeviceClass.VideoCapture))
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.EnclosureLocation != null && x.EnclosureLocation.Panel == desired);

    if (deviceID != null) return deviceID;
    else throw new Exception(string.Format("Camera of type {0} doesn't exist.", desired));
}

async private void InitCamera_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var cameraID = await GetCameraID(Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Panel.Back);
    captureManager = new MediaCapture();
    await captureManager.InitializeAsync(new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings
        {
            StreamingCaptureMode = StreamingCaptureMode.Video,
            PhotoCaptureSource = PhotoCaptureSource.Photo,
            AudioDeviceId = string.Empty,
            VideoDeviceId = cameraID.Id                    
        });
}
```

Comment: @user3627550 I've added choosing the camera device (front/back).

Comment: I have implemented everything like you have but when I want to take a photo the preview is flipped 180 degrees but looks ok when I hold the phone in landscape mode. Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: @IvanCrojachKaračić Once, I've written a [blog post](http://www.romasz.net/how-to-take-a-photo-in-windows-runtime/), take a look at it. The default preview is rotated, in `StartPreviewBtn_Click` you will find: `captureManager.SetPreviewRotation(VideoRotation.Clockwise90Degrees);` - this should do the job.

Comment: also add captureManager.SetPreviewMirroring(false);

Comment: @user3290180 This depends on user's needs.

Comment: SetPreviewRotation must be called after InitializeAsync.

Comment: @Jensen It seems to be logic - first initialize camera, before setting/modifying it's properties.

Comment: @Romasz , for this example I could marry you. THANKS!

Comment: @Yogurtu I'm glad you have found it useful. SO - a matrimonial service, thankfully it's a very rare case when somebody wants to merry me for a post :)

Answer (score 3):

In universal Windows Phone 8.1 (WinRT) apps it is no longer possible to jump directly into the built-in camera app and receive a callback when a picture was taken.

To do that you have to implement `Windows.Media.Capture.MediaCapture` as described above. There used to be `CameraCatureUI` but it is not available in WinRT apps for Windows Phone 8.1.

**However there is a "workaround".** You can use `Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker` and configure it to pick images. Now the picker will have a camera-button. The user can click the camera-button and the built-in camera app will open. Once the user has taken a picture you will receive a callback in your app. The `FileOpenPicker` callback is a little annoying to implement, but it works. If you can live with the usability implications this might be a valid approach.

There was a session on this topic during Microsofts build-Conference in 2014. [You can watch the session online with this link.](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2014/2-525)

Comment: this is case with phone only, what about phone store app?

Answer (score 0):

You can take the approach on [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202956%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) link. Everything is explained very nicely.

Just use the `PhotoCamera` class and don't forget to enable camera usage in your app manifest

Comment: Well, thank you, but the point is that i need to complete a windows store app. The windows 8.1 apps use the windows runtime and this API is very different from the silverlight apps. And, of course, the complete API is not implemented for windows phone : some class very useful and simple that you can use for Windows 8.1 won't be usable for windows phone, and i can't find the others solutions.