# How can I use CameraTask or PhotoChooser in window phone 8.1?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I'm developing a WP81 app, and I have some troble in capturing image from camera.
I want to capture camera or select photo in piture hub with simple method like WP71's CameraTask or PhotoChooser.
But I cannot find any other similar method in WP81's sdk.
Does anyone know the similar apis?

WP71's CameraTask, PhotoChooser api:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394006(v=vs.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394006%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

WP81's raw and complicated camera api:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn642091.aspx

Comment: As for complicated Camera API, if you want to take a photo - [this answer may help](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23606620/2681948).

Comment: @Romasz Thank you :). But I am looking for more simple apies like WP71's simple CameraTask. I do not want to create the custom shutter button separetely for every simple use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your link to WP71's Api works on Windows Phone (7 & 8).

For Windows Phone 8.1, I've find this : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn376408.aspx but the CameraCaptureUI control is not available on Windows Phone 8.1 devices. Use the lower-level [Windows.Media.Capture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.phone.media.capture.aspx) API instead: see [Quickstart: capturing video by using the MediaCapture api](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn642092.aspx) for more information.

Momentarily, you can use IoC pattern (if you have different projects, an interface on your common project, and 2 classes on your specific platforms projects, that inherit from the interface - and you call your methods on common project) or [if directives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/4y6tbswk.aspx)

Comment: What on earth in wrong with MS.  Now I have to have 3 different ways for Camera??  One for WP8.0, WP8.1 and Win8.1... so stupid.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
FileOpenPicker picker = new FileOpenPicker();
Helpers.FillDecoderExtensions(picker.FileTypeFilter);
picker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
```

Which opens the File Open picker, set to images, which gives the option of capturing a fresh image.

See http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2014/2-525  for more info.