# Photo capture with Windows Phone 8.1 and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to capture a Picture within a Windows Phone 8.1 app and I saw a very promising answer here at stockoverflow: [Photo capture on Windows Store App for Windows Phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23605967/photo-capture-on-windows-store-app-for-windows-phone)

But I am developing with JavaScript and HTML. Unfortunately I can not find a solution within this environment. In the stackoverflow answer [CaptureElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.captureelement) is mentioned but on the official site from Microsoft about the [CaptureElement class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.captureelement) one can read for javascript:

> No code example is currently available or this language may not be supported.

How is it possible to take a picture with JavaScript? 
Thanks a lot for any ideas!

Cheers,
Tim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally know what the difference is. One link helped me a lot: [MediaCapture.StartPreviewAsync is not available in javascript?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/206085a6-0db0-47b7-94e3-2e5be031c396/bug-mediacapturestartpreviewasync-is-not-available-in-javascript-?forum=winappswithhtml5) There is a link mentioned pointing to a sample source code: [Media capture using capture device sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Media-Capture-Sample-adf87622). The most important part:

```
mediaCapture = new Windows.Media.Capture.MediaCapture();
mediaCapture.initializeAsync().done(function(result){
    var video = this.document.getElementById("PhotoPreview");
    video.src = URL.createObjectURL(mediaCapture, { oneTimeOnly: true });
    video.play();
})
```

Thanks to everyone reading my question.