# Can't use videoBrush windows phone 8.1. Visual studio 2013 doesn't see System.Windows.Media

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

Visual studio 2013 doesn't see `System.Windows.Media`. I tried to find `PresentationCore.dll` (like in [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/fdfff143-c1ae-41cd-bbeb-8ff6c1c879ec/cannot-find-systemwindowsmediaimaging-namespace) case), but i don't have any folder named `Framework`.

When i try to get this folder from a different source (friend's notebook), I can use `System.Windows.Media`, but it doesn't compile, because this file has a different architecture. I tried to repair .NET but it had no effect.

If I cannot install this feature, how can I get an image from the camera in real time?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Photo capture on Windows Store App for Windows Phone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23605967/photo-capture-on-windows-store-app-for-windows-phone)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use CaptureElement control: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.captureelement.aspx

Comment: You saved me. Thank to you, i found the same trouble: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23605967/photo-capture-on-windows-store-app-for-windows-phone