# VideoBrush is not supported in a windows phone project

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am using VS2013 to write a windows phone camera app.

In xaml file, an error says  was not found.

Does anyone know what assembly reference do I need to add?

The references I have are

1. .NET for Windows Store Apps
2. Microsoft.Phone
3. Microsoft.Xna.Framework
4. PresentationCore
5. PresentationFramework
6. Windows Phone 8.1

The namespaces I use are:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Devices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you post the error message in full or at least the name of the missing item?

Comment: The full error msg is : The type 'VideoBrush' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.

Comment: Not sure, but you might need to create a `Windows Phone Silverlight` App instead of a `Windows Phone` App in order to be able to use [VideoBrush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.windows.media.videobrush(v=vs.105).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I think:

You should use CaptureElement control: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.captureelement.aspx

from: 
[Can't use videoBrush windows phone 8.1. Visual studio 2013 doesn't see System.Windows.Media](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24845488/cant-use-videobrush-windows-phone-8-1-visual-studio-2013-doesnt-see-system-wi)