# How to use the camera windows phone?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

Unable to reach the PhotoCamera
[image]

Tried all the examples from the internet , do not work. Help start the camera in any way , please.

Comment: I believe you want the Microsoft.Devices namespace: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/microsoft.devices.photocamera(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: @Josh 
what are the alternatives?

Comment: Why can you not use Microsoft.Devices.PhotoCamera?

Comment: @Josh I can not find Microsoft.Devices.PhotoCamera. 
This can be seen in my screenshot.
I am new to programming in windows phone, and do not know what I'm doing wrong ...

Comment: Your screenshot shows **Windows**.Devices, not **Microsoft**.Devices

Comment: @Josh In Microsoft no Devices. I have only to Microsoft CSharp and VisualBasic=(

Comment: Apologies, looks like you should be using Windows.Media.Capture, here is a comprehensive answer on a previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23605967/photo-capture-on-windows-store-app-for-windows-phone

Answer (score 0):

Use `Microsoft.Devices.PhotoCamera()` in Windows Phone Silverlight project.
While use `Windows.Media.Capture.CameraCaptureUI` API to capture a photo in winrt project.

Comment: can not find no Microsoft.Devices.PhotoCamera (), not Windows.Media.Capture.CameraCaptureUI

Comment: @АлексейГерусенко You can use Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker and configure it to pick images. A comprehensive answer is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23605967/photo-capture-on-windows-store-app-for-windows-phone).

Answer (score 0):

**Under AppManifest.xml --> Capabilites --> Tick ID_CAP_ISV_CAMERA** give this permission to your app.

```
CameraCaptureTask cameraCaptureTask = new CameraCaptureTask();
cameraCaptureTask.Completed += new EventHandler<PhotoResult>(cameraCaptureTask_Completed);
cameraCaptureTask.Show();

void cameraCaptureTask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
{
    try
    {
        if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
        {
            // your code after get image capture
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```