# Change the default camera app in Windows 10 desktop

Tags: camera, uwp

How to change the default camera app in Windows 10 desktop ? The option is available from Settings in Phones but not from Desktops

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make 'advanced' photo capture, then you can use [MediaCapture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.media.capture.mediacapture) class. Everything about this you will find [at MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/camera). There are also quite nice samples [at GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CameraAdvancedCapture).

It also seems that [my old post for WinRT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23606620/2681948) is still quite relevant. You will find there that I'm using *GetCameraID*:

```cs
private static async Task<DeviceInformation> GetCameraID(Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Panel desired)
{
    DeviceInformation deviceID = (await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(DeviceClass.VideoCapture))
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.EnclosureLocation != null && x.EnclosureLocation.Panel == desired);

    if (deviceID != null) return deviceID;
    else throw new Exception(string.Format("Camera of type {0} doesn't exist.", desired));
}
```

to choose a device to be used to capture the photo. In your app you can enumerate devices and choose the one that suits you.